# Работа с массивами JavaScript, зеркальные массивы

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
var array = ["qwe", "asd", "zxc"];
```

На выходе надо получить полностью зеркальный ответ. т.е.

> "cxz","dsa","ewq"

Как развернуть массив, знаю, справился, а вот как перевернуть строки не совсем понимаю. Есть такое решение:

```
var array=["qwe", "asd", "zxc"]; 
var a = array.reverse();
```

Но что со строками делать не знаю, подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты решения.

Знаю, что надо пройти по масиву и каждый элемент массива(строчку). Разложить, массив развернуть и соединить обратно в строку, но как реализовать не понимаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
var a = ["qwe", "asd", "zxc"];
var b = a.reverse().map(function(aa){
        return aa.split("").reverse().join("");
   });
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Дал ясности

Answer (score 3):

Предположив, что в строках точно не может быть, скажем, нулевого символа `\0`, можно всё склеить в одну строку через этот разделитель, реверснуть, и разбить по нему:

```
var a = ["qwe", "asd", "zxc"];
var d = "\0";
var b = a.join(d).split('').reverse().join('').split(d); // ["cxz","dsa","ewq"]
```

Недостаток метода в разделителе: строки точно не должны содержать этот символ.

Comment: И этот вариант хорош, согласен, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = ["qwe", "asd", "zxc"];
var r=a.map(e=>[...e].sort(v=>-1).join``).reverse();
console.log(r);
```